# Want to make output as an Object instead of println

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach

I want to make an object instead of println.

text file would be like
"nagano,apple"
"nagano,pear"
"texas,grapefruit"
"rio,guava"
"rio,guava"

and result like
"(nagano,apple,1)"
"(nagano,pear,1)"
"(texas,grapefruit,1)"
"(rio,guava,2)"

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("WordCount")
    .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // read text info
    val textfile = sc.textFile("C:\\fruitbox.csv")
    twitter.filter(_.nonEmpty)
    val map = twitter.map { word => (word, 1) }
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .foreach(println) // ← want to do something about this row
}
```

but I want to make println result to be like this

```
    .foreach(
        fruitbox.setCity(_.split(",")[0])
        fruitbox.setApple(_.split(",")[1])
        ...
    )
```

it seems like simple knowledge of syntax
but I couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of it in functional terms or you will get crazy. Replace the `foreach` with a `map` that takes a function of this form:

```
.map(myInputTuple=>MyCaseClass(myInputTuple._0,myInputTuple._1,myInputTuple._2))
```

Do you know case classes? If you don't, you should give it a look and define your own to hold the data you deal with. Otherwise, if you want to build a specific instance of an already existing class that has setters, you can do it this way:

```
.map(myInputTuple=>{
val myInstance = new myClass()
myInstance.setField1(myInputTuple._0)
...
myInstance
}
)
```

Mind the brackets: `{}` these define a scope where you can write non-functional code and the last value of this scope will be the value returned, in this case the instance of your class.

Also when you post stuff about Spark, try to make explicit the types you're dealing with at every step so it's easier to write code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help Chobeat!
I fixed foreach to map and added some rows
but compiler skips it..
am I missing something?

```
val map = twitter.map { word => (word, 1) }
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map(obj => { // ← SKIPS FROM HERE
    var arg = obj._1.split(",")
    val twitterInfo = new TwitterInfo(arg.apply(0), arg.apply(1), obj._2)
    list:+=(twitterInfo)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the 'list :+= (twitterinfo)' ?
You should not use mutable state, but return a result from the 'map' function instead.

Also, I noticed in the question the 'twitter.filter' and 'twitter.map' are 2 different expressions both using 'twitter' variable as start point which means the 'filter' is not used and you still map over the empty records.